# Why would a simple `git mv` fail?

Tags: git

I am trying to rename a file in a local `.git directory`:

```
git mv MyProj/src/ts0621/foobar.c NewProjName/src/ts0629/foobar.c
```

Yet, git fails with:

```
fatal: renaming 'MyProj/src/ts0621/foobar.c' failed: No such file or directory
```

I could swear that I had `git mv` working for me when renaming a subdirectory, but for some reason a simple rename of a file doesn't work. Why?

(I, of course, verified that the file `MyProj/src/ts0621/foobar.c` exists before attempting to issue this command)

Comment: Does the directory `NewProjName/src/ts0629` exist as well?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably, because NewProjName/src/ts0629 doesn't exist

Try

```
mkdir -pv NewProjName/src/ts0629
git add NewProjName/src/ts0629
```

Comment: It's true that NewProjName/src/ts0629 doesn't exist, but in the past, something like `git mv OldProj/src/ts0619 MyProj/src/ts0621` never failed despite `MyProj/src/ts0621` not existing. Is git treating directories differently than files?

Comment: @WinWin: The difference is in the nesting level; git is treating _nested_ files differently; It will not automatically create _and add_ the missing parent directories _and make them tracked_ all at once. Chances are, that wouldn't be what you wanted in case of typo's

Comment: OK. If that's the case, I would say that git's error message is misleading. :) It should accompany `No such file or directory` with the non-existent destination path, not the existing source path. For lack of a better option, I am going to use your workaround.

Comment: @WinWin: the message is a sideeffect of git's support for e.g. `git mv 1/a 1/b 2/c 2/d dest/`; It will mention the _source path_ because it might not be clear what path it fails for if `dest` _does_ exist

Comment: I understand, but I think it's still possible to improve the error message (requires detailed "if exist" for each argument). Anyway your workaround works perfectly, so accepting. Thanks again.

Comment: It's rant time! I ran into this today and this is an example of git's avoidable usability issues. Yes, there's a "reason" it happened, but it's more of an excuse. Most systems would identify this as a bug but it's whisked away as "by design" merely because it can be explained. There are plenty of ways to solve this, and one that most assuredly wouldn't impact design is simply a better error message as WinWin stated. Besides, this is a simple use case. Isn't there something wrong when I stumble around trying to move a file into a directory?

Comment: @JohnnyKauffman you mean, when you stumble around trying to move a file into a directory which doesn't exist? I agree that Git's accessibility (and the error message) leaves a lot to be desired, but I'm not sure if any other VCS'es handle this significantly better

Comment: @jalf If it requires clarification, my point is merely that it's unintuitive. We also all seem to agree that it would an improvement if the error message was clearer.

Comment: @JohnnyKauffman No, your point was to rant. You said that quite clearly. ;) You also said it was a simple use case, and that "most systems would identify this as a bug". I don't think that's true. Otherwise, every VCS I've ever used has suffered from this "bug". I think they all identify it as "by design". So does the plain unix `mv`, btw. It can't move into nonexistent directories either. Is `mv` buggy? Your *other* point, that the error message could be better is... true

Comment: @jalf No, that's just a semantics disagreement over the word "bug". For example, why not just change all the errors to "It didn't work!". It would certainly be accurate, so would it be a "bug"? In my world, yes. Also, I can clarify on what I hate about the "by design" excuse: it is too often used when things are unintuitive.

Comment: 10 years later and I just ran into this same issue. I'd like to point out that Git tracks files, not folders, so a folder not existing shouldn't be an issue for Git because Git doesn't track them anyways. This is an issue of Git's model of a repository not quite matching up with the file system, and Git giving up instead of handling its own disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

add -f ,  if the path is relative, to increase `git mv -f "originPath" "newPath"`

```
git mv -f MyProj/src/ts0621/foobar.c NewProjName/src/ts0629/foobar.c
```